# How to pull data based on current and last update?

Tags: sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

Our data table looks like this:

| Machine Name | Lot Number | Qty | Load TxnDate | Unload TxnDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M123 | ABC | 500 | 10/1/2020 | 10/2/2020 |
| M741 | DEF | 325 | 10/1/2020 |  |
| M123 | ZZZ | 100 | 10/5/2020 | 10/7/2020 |
| M951 | AAA | 550 | 10/5/2020 | 10/9/2020 |
| M123 | BBB | 550 | 10/7/2020 |  |

I need to create an SQL query that shows the currently loaded Lot number - Machines with no Unload TxnDate - and the last loaded Lot number based on the unload TxnDate.

So in the example, when I run a query for **M123**, the result will show:

| Machine Name | Lot Number | Qty | Load TxnDate | Unload TxnDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M123 | ZZZ | 100 | 10/5/2020 | 10/7/2020 |
| M123 | BBB | 550 | 10/7/2020 |  |

As you can see although Machine Name has 3 records, the results only show the currently loaded and the last loaded. Is there anyway to replicate this? The Machine Name is dynamic, so my user can enter the Machine Name and see the results the machine based on the missing **Unload TxnDate** and the last **Unload Txn Date**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the last two rows.  That would be something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where machine_name = 'M123'
order by load_txn_date desc
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

Note:  not all databases support the `first first` clause.  Some spell it `limit`, or `select top`, or even something else.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you. But if Machine_Name is dynamic how would that work? Meaning that if Machine Name would have 30 records, how would the system look for the last two update?

Comment: @lostcoder . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two rows *per machine*, one option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by machine_name, (case when unload_txn_date is null then 0 else 1 end) 
            order by coalesce(unload_txn_date, load_txn_date) desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The idea is to separate rows between those that have an unload date, and those that do not. We can then bring the top record per group.

For your sample data, [this returns](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccc43f0b25618eccc759e1579611eb76):

```
Machine_Name | Lot_Number | Qty | Load_Txn_Date | Unload_Txn_Date | rn
:----------- | :--------- | --: | :------------ | :-------------- | -:
M123         | BBB        | 550 | 2020-10-07    | null            |  1
M123         | ZZZ        | 100 | 2020-10-05    | 2020-10-07      |  1
M741         | DEF        | 325 | 2020-10-01    | null            |  1
M951         | AAA        | 550 | 2020-10-05    | 2020-10-09      |  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following query, presuming that you're on a database having Window(or Analytic) Function

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT COALESCE(Unload_Txn_Date - 
                 LAG(Load_Txn_Date) OVER 
                 (PARTITION BY Machine_Name ORDER BY Load_Txn_Date DESC),0) AS lg,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Unload_Txn_Date IS NULL THEN Load_Txn_Date END) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY Machine_Name) AS mx,   
        t.*
   FROM tab t
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY mx DESC NULLS LAST) AS dr, t.*
   FROM t
  WHERE mx IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Machine_Name,Lot_Number,Qty,Load_Txn_Date,Unload_Txn_Date
  FROM t2
 WHERE dr = 1 AND lg = 0 
 ORDER BY Load_Txn_Date
```

where if previous row's `Unload_Txn_Date` is equal to the current `Load_Txn_Date`, then it's accepted that there's no interruption will occur for the job, while determining the last Unload Txn Dates with no unload date values per each machine. And then, the result set returns through filtering by the values derived from the window functions within the penultimate query.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb753886d8e4b366681d34610a74aa0a)</kbd>